# How to fit linear model after principal component analysis

Tags: r, statistics, data-mining

I've done a princomp analysis on four columns of my dataframe, and found that the first component is overwhelmingly more important than the other three.

Now I want to fit a linear model using the first component only. How do I get the new data made up of only this component?

I understand that there's some matrix multiplication involved, but I have no idea how to do this. I've googled and googled and can't find anything comprehensible.

Comment: The first component is always going to be "the most important".  You may want to use parallel analysis as well to determine how many components you should be extracting.  Also check out the `pcr` function in the pcl package for PCA regression (though I've never used this myself)

Comment: On the other hand, one of the other PCs may be the one that's actually correlated with your response.  Far better to use a method of dimension reduction designed for use in a regression, when that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scores are the transformed data using the principal components. I think `prcomp` and `princomp` yield these as an output. Then just select the first column. Take a look at the documentation of `princomp` or `prcomp` (`?prcomp`, `?princomp`), specifically at the Value section (which describes what the function returns) and the examples section.

Comment: How do they yeild them as an output? How do I get that column? This is what I can't figure out! All I can see are the results in terms of contributions to variance.

Comment: See `?princomp` where its says the scores are in a list element called `scores`.  So if you did `ans <- princomp(data, etc)` then `ans$scores[,1]` contains your first set of scores (one for each object/sample, so that's what you want as input to your linear fit).  Depending upon how you used `princomp`, watch out for the argument `scores = TRUE`